# Xcode 5 - Wireless install app to device option?

Tags: xcode, build, wireless

The option is gone from the general preferences pane, and I cant find any results for Xcode 5 on how to enable it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This feature was not available after 4.2. Neither 4.3.1 nor 4.5 or 4.6 had this feature. And up to now Xcode 5 does not seems to have this feature. We can hope for its return , but it is dead for now.

Comment: may be iOS 6, just downloaded the beta version, will find out

Comment: @shebelaw, have you seen this in iOS 6 as well? I can't seem to find it.